# Ajax - Find, Filter or another?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have pagination on a table, this table is with `id="#content-of-table"`.

in the pagination links I left `href="#"` and inserted the urls into `data-href`

```
"<a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Back</a>";
```

But I have two columns on my page, I use bootstrap, the first column has the form and the second the table

When I click on the pagination the entire page is loaded into the table `id="#content-of-table"`

Jquery

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $.ajax({
         url: url,

         success: function (response) {
              $('#content-of-table').html(response)
         }
   });
})
```

I tried using filter:

```
success: function (response) {
     $(response).filter('#content-of-table').html()
}
```

And find:

```
success: function (response) {
    $(response).find('#content-of-table').html()
}
```

But neither worked

I'm trying to load just the content of the id inside the table and not the entire page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` should work, but there is a way to actually make sure you find the element, even if it's not a descendant element that `find()` normally can't find, and that is by making it a descendant, by using a new parent element.

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');
   $.ajax({
       url     : url,
       success : function (response) {
           var html = $('<div />', {html : response}).find('#content-of-table').html();
           $('#content-of-table').html( html )
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this way when clicking this is going correctly to the content of the first click on one of the pagination items. But then it freezes the buttons and it is not possible to go to any other page

Comment: Is `.page-link` inside `#content-of-table` by any change? Did you open the console and check for errors?

Comment: Yes it was on the last line of the table, I took the table and now it's working ok, thank you very much